# HAProxy Mailer SMTP Authentication

Tags: haproxy, mailer

I would like to send alerts using a mailer in HAProxy.
I tried to follow:
[email-alert](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#email-alert%20from)

The problem is that my mail server requires a SSL connection with username an password.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution.

Following (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) I've configured a local postfix.

HAProxy connects to this SMTP server to send mails.